# python: issue with handling csv object in an iteration

Tags: python, csv

First, sorry if the title is not clear. I (noob) am baffled by this...

Here's my code:

```
import csv
from random import random
from collections import Counter

def rn(dic, p):
    for ptry in parties:
        if p < float(dic[ptry]):
            return ptry
        else:
            p -= float(dic[ptry])


def scotland(r):
    r['SNP'] = 48
    r['Con'] += 5
    r['Lab'] += 1
    r['LibDem'] += 5


def n_ireland(r):
    r['DUP'] = 9
    r['Alliance'] = 1
    # SF = 7


def election():
    results = Counter([rn(row, random()) for row in data])
    scotland(results)
    n_ireland(results)
    return results


parties = ['Con', 'Lab', 'LibDem', 'Green', 'BXP', 'Plaid', 'Other']

with open('/Users/andrew/Downloads/msp.csv', newline='') as f:
    data = csv.DictReader(f)
    for i in range(1000):
        print(election())
```

What happens is that in every iteration after the first one, the variable `data` seems to have vanished: the function `election()` creates a Counter object from a list obtained by processing `data`, but on every pass after the first one, this object is empty, so the function just returns the hard coded data from `scotland()` and `n_ireland()`. (`msp.csv` is a csv file containing detailed polling data). I'm sure I'm doing something stupid but would welcome anyone gently pointing out where...

Comment: oh...a thought: is csv.DictReader something like an API call, so once it has read the data once it has no more data to read? If so, how can I change ```data``` into a persistent object like a dictionary?

Comment: You're not passing data to the election() function.

Comment: Hi@Bober I don't know what you mean, sorry. I was assuming that ```data``` is a dictionary-like object which is is global by default (I know that's not technically accurate, but you know what I mean). I tested this by making data explicitly global, but it doesn't make any difference. If the problem was in variable referencing in election(), I don't see why it would work on the first pass but not the second. My sense of what is happening is that the first pass of election() reads the file to its end, and then there is no data left to read, somehow

Answer (score 2):

I’m going to place a bet on your definition of *newline*. Are you sure you don’t want newline = “\n” ? Otherwise it will interpret the entire file as a single line, which explains what you’re seeing.

**EDIT**

I now see another issue. The file object in python acts as a generator for each line. The problem is once the generator is finished (you hit the end of the file), you have no more data `generated`. To solve this: reset your file pointer to the beginning of the file like so:

```
with open('/Users/andrew/Downloads/msp.csv') as f:
    data = csv.DictReader(f)
    for i in range(1000):
        print(election())
        f.seek(0)
```

Here the call to `f.seek(0)` will reset the file pointer to the beginning of your file. You are correct that `data` is a global object given the way you've defined it at the module level, there's no need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I tried this and it made no difference. The code runs perfectly the first time through the iteration, and if I expand it to see what is going on, it doesn't behave as if it is interpreting the file as a single line: it's parsing the rows correctly. The second time through, it seems to have forgotten that the object ```data``` is not empty

Comment: Thanks @smassey that nearly worked...after f.seek(0) I had to set up ```data``` again - I think because DictReader takes the first line as the dictionary keys. Probably I can use f.seek(n) where n is the start of the second line, though my ugly repeating of the ```data = ``` line worked and run time is not as bad as I feared. thanks for your help

Comment: Update in case of use to anyone: changing data to ```list(csv.DictReader(f))``` changes it from a generator to a list and that solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @smassey, you might need to change the code to

```
with open('/Users/andrew/Downloads/msp.csv', newline='\n') as f:
```

or simply try not use that argument

```
with open('/Users/andrew/Downloads/msp.csv') as f:
```

Comment: @andrew, is there a way you can post your csv?

Comment: I guess so, though if it's just to help me, then thanks but I think I've got it, with help from smassey: as DictReader is a generator, I was 'using up' the data on the first pass. In v2 I just recreated the object each pass and that worked, and then I realised that all I had to do was change ```data``` to be ```list(csv.Dictreader(f))``` to use the generator to create a list. If it's the data itself that's of interest, ping me back and I'll send it to you